# get the longest hierarchy

Tags: php, sql, mysql

In the DataBase i Stored the Some information(represented in the Attached ScreenShot)
[image]

what is the best way to get the longest hierarchy id?
in the attached pic the longest hierarchy is 128 ,because it has the least number of 0's values  in it's fields(t_definition_types_id_(1-4))

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way is like :

```
SELECT id,
 (IF(t_definition_types_id_1>0, 1, 0) + 
  IF(t_definition_types_id_2>0, 1, 0) +
  IF(t_definition_types_id_3>0, 1, 0) +
  IF(t_definition_types_id_4>0, 1, 0) 
) 
AS level 
FROM mytable ORDER BY level DESC
```

Comment: This won't give the higher-numbered-columns precedence, which I assumed was the point - but again, it's unclear. If it's possible for `id_2` and `id_3` to be zero, but `id_4` to be nonzero, then this is the way to go. Otherwise, the method I suggested will require less processing time. @ahmad can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for replay, if id_2 for example is 0 so all value after it also will be zero.Neil the ids(t_definition_types_ids) represent the ids of employemnt hierarchy,so for example if the user does not enter hos department id,he cant enter his section id,so, and for that if id_2 is zero ,all the values after will be zero.
So i want to get the most specific hierarchy for employee which is the longest one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY 
    t_definition_types_id_4 DESC, 
    t_definition_types_id_3 DESC, 
    t_definition_types_id_2 DESC, 
    t_definition_types_id_1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The question's a tad foggy but I *think* that's what you're trying to do. Correct me if I'm wrong.